# how to convert a matrix of matrices into single NxN matrix in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix that has matrices within it, how do I flatten into a single matrix.
For example, I have something like :

```
import numpy as np
P = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
O = np.zeros([2,2])
M = np.array([[P,O],[O,P])
```

I want to recover a 4x4 matrix, by flattening M. How do I convert a matrix of matrices into a single Matrix, I using numpy and python?

Comment: You could make M using numpy.block: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html

Comment: will I get a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: It would be 4x4. You can compare to the examples in the link I gave.

Comment: This is not working